# Scrapy: different results from shell and script

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get some data (text, url and views) from the [website](https://opendata.socrata.com/).

I tired to scrap it in the scrapy shell first and everything works fine. 
But when I move the same code into my socrata_basr.py, only views have result back and text and url is empty.

My  socrata_basr.py code:

```
# socrata_base.py - basespider

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from socrata.items import SocrataItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "socrata"
    allowed_domains = ["opendata.socrata.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://opendata.socrata.com"
            ]

    def parse(self, response):    
        hxs = Selector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath('//tr[@itemscope="itemscope"]')
        items = []
        for t in titles:
             item = SocrataItem()
             item["text"] = t.xpath("td[2]/div[1]/a/text()").extract()
             item["url"] = t.xpath("td[2]/div[1]/a[@href]/@href").extract()
             item["views"] = t.xpath("td[3]/span/text()").extract()
             items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

My pipeline code:

```
import sqlite3

class SocrataPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('project.db')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cur.execute("insert into data (text, url, views) values(?,?,?)", (item['text'][0], item['url'][0], item['views'][0]))
        self.conn.commit()
        return item
```

If I run it, I will have index out of rang error in this line of code:

```
self.cur.execute("insert into data (text, url, views) values(?,?,?)", (item['text'][0], item['url'][0], item['views'][0]))
```

If I change the code to:

```
self.cur.execute("insert into data (text, url, views) values(?,?,?)", ("text", "url", item['views'][0]))
```

It works fine and I will have correct "views" result stored.
So I believe I don't get any result back for text and url, that's why I will have the  index out of rang error.

But I test the same scrapy code in shell and all text, url, views are corrected return.

My items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class SocrataItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    text = Field()
    url = Field()
    views = Field()
```

My soc_bd.py:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("project.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE data (text TEXT,url TEXT, views TEXT)''')
```

I don't know what's wrong!
Please help!

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you see correct item in the console when you disable your pipeline?

Comment: @pault. I don't know how to disable the pipeline. I tried it out on shell and had correct item. Thanks!

Comment: you can disable your Pipeline by undoing what you did to enable it in the first place, i.e. edit your `settings.py` and remove the line with `socrata.pipelines.SocrataPipeline`.
But note that I'm able to run your code without problem if I predefine the table schema in `project.db`.

Comment: @pault. I disable pipeline and the both text and url are empty but views has result back. I added my db definition to the post.